# ggplot2 differences between local and Shiny-hosted output

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I've noticed an unexpected difference in the rendering of a `ggplot` between local output and a Shiny application. The axes labels are entirely different:

Local:
[image]
Shiny App:
[image]

The axes of the two plots differ by exactly 1 day - how very odd! What happened during the publishing to Shiny process?

## Data

```
data.df <- structure(list(Report.Date = structure(c(1430434800, 1433026800, 
1435618800, 1438297200, 1440975600, 1443567600, 1430434800, 1433026800, 
1435618800, 1438297200, 1440975600, 1443567600), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Datasets.Deposited", "Datasets.Published"
), class = "factor"), value = c(0L, 21L, 32L, 43L, 56L, 73L, 
0L, 4L, 9L, 21L, 29L, 49L)), .Names = c("Report.Date", "variable", 
"value"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

## Local code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
base <- ggplot(data.df, aes(Report.Date, value))
plot <- base + geom_area(aes(group = variable, fill= variable), position = 'identity') + geom_point(aes(color = series), color = "black")
plot <- plot + xlab("Date") + ylab("Number of Deposits/Published")
plot  +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,round(max(data.df$value)+5,-1),5)) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 month"), labels = date_format("%Y-%b-%d"), minor_breaks = "1 month") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

## Shiny

ui.R

```
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
)
```

server.R

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
shinyServer(
  function(input, output){
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      data.df <- 
      base <- ggplot(data.df, aes(Report.Date, value))
      plot <- base + geom_area(aes(group = variable, fill= variable), position = 'identity') + geom_point(aes(color = series), color = "black")
      plot <- plot + xlab("Date") + ylab("Number of Deposits/Published")
      plot  +
        scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,round(max(data.df$value)+5,-1),5)) +
        scale_x_datetime(breaks = "1 month", labels = date_format("%d-%b-%Y"), minor_breaks = "1 month") + 
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
    }
    )
  }
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1430434800 seconds since Unix epoch is 30 Apr 2015 23:00:00 GMT, which is dangerously close to end of the day.

When `tz` argument to `as.POSIX*` functions is missing or empty string, [current (machine-dependent) timezone will be used](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html).

It seems that you are currently at GMT or west, while R Shiny server is at GMT+1 or east. These two computers evaluate the same fixed point in time into different "wall-clock" times, and since reference point is close to midnight, there is artificial change of date.

To fix that, you should provide timezone definition, so POSIX* functions don't have to fallback to unpredictable default.

Looks like you can do that by giving `tzone` property an "GMT" value:

`data.df <- structure(list(Report.Date = structure(c(1430434800, 1433026800, 
1435618800, 1438297200, 1440975600, 1443567600, 1430434800, 1433026800, 
1435618800, 1438297200, 1440975600, 1443567600), tzone = "GMT", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), …`

Comment: Great! Thanks, I'll look into this - as you saw I'm GMT, so I'll try this in the morning.

Comment: This worked for me - I think it's useful to note there was an issue on `ggplot2` about "scale_x_datetime converts POSIXct to local timezone" that I found aftet you gave me the hat tip to timezones being the issue - https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/533